# I am trying to submit form through voice command

Tags: jquery, voice-recognition

I am trying to submit form through voice command but I cannot figure out how to submit it through form!

```
function passwordChangeAndSubmit() {
ask('Do you want me to change it?', function (err, result) {
    if (result && result.transcript == "yes") {
        password()
    }
    else if (result && result.transcript == "no") {
        $('signupForm').submit();
    }
});
```

This line

```
else if (result && result.transcript == "no") {
        $('signupForm').submit();
    }
```

does work when I say 'no'

Is there anything missing?

Comment: Have you tried using `.trigger("submit")` method instead of `.submit()`?  Does it solve your problem?

Comment: No man! it doesnt